# Python - hangman replacing letters and updating with count

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def update(dictionary,letter):

    if letter in dictionary["word"]:
```

I am making hangman game and I am stuck on how I can make my last function so that when a letter is guess

Comment: I feel like this should be a class. In `returnString` and `guess` you use the key `guess` instead of `guessWord`. Are you using `upper()` or `lower()` on `secretWord` and `letter` before they are passed in?

Answer (score 2):

```
if letter in dictionary['word'] and letter not in dictionary['guessWord']:
    dictionary['guessWord'] = ''.join([i if i in dictionary['guessWord'] or i == letter 
                                         else '*' for i in dictionary['word']])
else:
    dictionary['lives'] -= 1
```

This techniques rebuilds `guessWord` from the secret word every time.  `join` takes a list of strings and joins them together with a separator, in this case `''`.  For each character in the secret word, we examine whether that character is equal to `letter` or is already in the guessword.  If so, it is put in the guessword.  If not, it is replaced with `*`

Comment: this `and letter not in dictionary['guessWord']` will make the player lose one life point if he tries an already guessed letter.  Ex: word: hell*, lives: 3 ==> guess: l ==>  word: hell*, lives: 2

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over tuples `(character in word, character in guess)`. If `letter` given to `update` matches with character in correct answer then pick it, otherwise pick the current guess and `join` the picked characters together. Finally check if new guess same as current and in case they match reduce lives:

```
def update(dictionary, letter):
    old = dictionary['guessWord']
    dictionary['guessWord'] = ''.join(x if x == letter else y
                                      for x, y in zip(dictionary['word'], old))
    if old == dictionary['guessWord']:
        dictionary['lives'] -= 1
```